# SEO Friendly Route with localization support

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

After following several tutorials, mainly [this one](https://irensaltali.com/en/asp-net-core-mvc-localization-by-url-routedatarequestcultureprovider/) I managed to implement localization support in my Asp.Net Core 3.1 website but now the routing doesn't seem to work properly. Here are my routes:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "TVShowsDetails",
        pattern: "tvshows/{id:int}/{*title}",
        defaults: new { controller = "tvshows", action = "details", id = 0 }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "LocalizedDefault",
        pattern: "{lang:lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", lang = "et" });

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Now when I create a link using this code: `<a asp-controller="TVShows" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@id" asp-route-title="@title">` for some reason the link it creates is something like this: `https://localhost:44349/en/tvshows/details/1?title=title`. Interestingly if I go to this link: `https://localhost:44349/en/tvshows/1/title` it shows the same page. I tried `href="Url.Action(...)"` but it generates the same result.

If I remove the `{lang:lang}/` at the beginning of the pattern however, it generates the correct link without the language part (`https://localhost:44349/tvshows/details/1?title=title`) but I need to generate the links with the current language so what am I missing?

### Edit

After several tries, this works:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "tvshowdetails",
    pattern: "{lang:lang}/{controller=tvshows}/{action=details}/{id?}/{title}"
);
```

But, I don't want to have the action name there (`details`). This produces the following link:

`https://localhost:44349/en/tvshows/details/1/breaking-bad`

I want the following link, however:

`https://localhost:44349/en/tvshows/1/breaking-bad`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some problems with URL generation schemes like yours as of .NET Core 3.0, as described in [the routing documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#problems-with-route-value-invalidation). Basically, the route values from the current request are not being included in the URL generation. [This post](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper#ambient-route-values) also suggests that it occurs when "the destination page is different to the source page."

The documentation suggests using legacy routing when faced with this problem. While I have no experience in doing so for .NET Core 3.0 projects, I do have a .NET Core 2.0 project from a few years ago that also used localised routes, so I do expect this to work.

Alternatively, you could explicitly pass the current language argument on to the anchor tag helper. From your original example, I got it to work with the following routing (note the added language parameter for the `TVShowsDetails` route)

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "TVShowsDetails",
        pattern: "{lang:lang}/tvshows/{id:int}/{*title}",
        defaults: new { controller = "tvshows", action = "details", id = 0 }
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "LocalizedDefault",
        pattern: "{lang:lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", lang = "et" });

    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

and then generating a link using

```
<a asp-controller="tvshows"
   asp-action="details"
   asp-route-lang="@Context.Request.RouteValues["lang"]"
   asp-route-id="@id"
   asp-route-title="@title">
```

Comment: I tried to use the named route, didn't work. It produces `https://localhost:44349/fa`.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori It did some more research, and edited my answer into a new answer. It seems this might be a known issue with .NET Core 3.0+ URL generation.